# Editable geoJSON layer on map with leaflet.draw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I try to load geoJson data in Mapbox and edit it with the plugin Leaflet.Draw
When i click to the edit button, i have an error :
Cannot set property 'original' of undefined

Layer is on the map, but I can't edit it.

Here is the code:

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView( [40, 40], 2);    

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox.streets',
      accessToken: '*******'
  }).addTo(map);

  // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
  var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
  map.addLayer(drawnItems);

  L.geoJson(<%=RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@field.shape).to_json.html_safe%>, 
      {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
      }
  }).addTo(map);

  // Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
  var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
      draw : {
        position : 'topleft',
        polygon : true,
        polyline : false,
        rectangle : false,
        circle : false,
        marker: false
      },
      edit: {
          featureGroup: drawnItems
      },
  }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found an answer.
I'm trying to edit multipolygon, but leaflet.draw dont support them.

I switched to leaflet.editable